# Remove white underline from MauiPicker in .net8

Tags: c#, android, maui

I can't seem to remove the white underline from the Maui picker after upgrading to .net8 for using Android.

I have tried adding a handler like this

**App.cs**

```
public App()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    MainPage = new AppShell();
            Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.PickerHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping(nameof(Picker), (handler, view) =>
            {
    #if ANDROID
                handler.PlatformView.Background = null; 
                handler.PlatformView.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
                handler.PlatformView.SetPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
    
                Android.Graphics.Drawables.GradientDrawable gd = new Android.Graphics.Drawables.GradientDrawable();
                gd.SetStroke(0, Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
                gd.SetColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
                handler.PlatformView.SetBackground(gd);
    #endif
            });
}
```

And also with a handler like this

**CleanPickerHandler.cs**

```
    public class CleanPickerHandler : PickerHandler
    {
#if ANDROID
        protected override void ConnectHandler(MauiPicker platformView)
        {
            base.ConnectHandler(platformView);

            platformView.Background = null;
            platformView.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
            platformView.SetPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);

            Android.Graphics.Drawables.GradientDrawable gd = new Android.Graphics.Drawables.GradientDrawable();
            gd.SetStroke(0, Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
            gd.SetColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
            platformView.SetBackground(gd);
        }
#endif
    }
```

**MauiProgram.cs**

```
public static class MauiProgram
{
    public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
    {
        var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();

        builder
            .UseMauiApp<App>()
            .UseMauiCommunityToolkit()
            .UseMauiCommunityToolkitMediaElement()
            .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
            {
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
                fonts.AddFont("Font Awesome 6 Brands-Regular-400.otf", "FontAwesomeBrands");
                fonts.AddFont("Font Awesome 6 Free-Regular-400.otf", "FontAwesomeRegular");
                fonts.AddFont("Font Awesome 6 Free-Solid-900.otf", "FontAwesomeSolid");
            })
            .ConfigureMauiHandlers(handlers =>
            {
#if ANDROID
                handlers.AddHandler(typeof(Picker), typeof(CleanPickerHandler));
#endif
            });
         ...
     }
}
```

I can see the padding getting removed, but the white underline still remains. Was there a change in .net8 that means I have to use a different method to remove the underline on the MauiPicker?

I was using the CleanPickerHandler in .net7 and it worked great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be a bug. You can report this as [a new issue for the maui](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues) on the github.

In addition, I found a workaround for this. You can put the code in the page's onhandler changed method. Such as:

In the Page.cs:

```
        protected override void OnHandlerChanged()
        {
            base.OnHandlerChanged();
#if ANDROID
            var view = picker.Handler.PlatformView as AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget.AppCompatEditText;
            view.Background = null;
            view.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
            view.SetPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);

            Android.Graphics.Drawables.GradientDrawable gd = new Android.Graphics.Drawables.GradientDrawable();
            gd.SetStroke(0, Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
            gd.SetColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
            view.SetBackground(gd);
#endif
        }
```

I tested this and the underline will disappear.  The way that can set for all the picker such as the custom handler seems stop working. It should be a new issue.

Comment: I have tried to implement your fix into my page behind where I am having this issue as well. The problem I am having is that I am missing something to provide my page with "picker.Handler.PlatformView" could you explain or show in your answer for future newbies like me how to set this up for the current context cheers. @Liyun Zhang - MSFT

Comment: In the xaml: <Picker x:Name="picker"/>. And in the code behind: picker.Handler.PlatformView. @AndyDonegan

Comment: Thank you, I should have figured that out myself but it is Monday morning hitting a brick wall @Liyun Zhang - MSFT